# JavaScript - Input a date then autopopulate next field with difference

Tags: javascript

Hi this is making me nuts. I am not a developer. Trying to get this to work.
User puts in a date (hire date) into form using Date object (calendar)
Next field should take that date and subtract todays date to get the length of employment. 
But I get undefined in the field AND my original hire date disappears.
Here is what I have, help please, much appreciation!

```
//grab date of hire
try{document.getElementById("dData_DOH").onchange =          custom_calculateDate;}catch(e){}
//not sure if necessary - field that the difference should go to
try{document.getElementById("dData_LengthEmp").onblur =     insertDate;}catch(e){}

//Function to grab input hire date 
//Create variable for now
//Create variable for difference


function custom_calculateDate(){
 var hireDate = document.getElementById("dData_DOH").value = "";
     var timeNow= new Date();
 var diff = Math.abs(timeNow - hireDate);
document.getElementById("dData_DOH").setAttribute('value',     custom_calculateDate());
     }

//Function to get the difference into the LengthEmp field    
function insertDate() {
document.getElementById("dData_LengthEmp").setAttribute("",     custom_calculateDate());
}
```

I know this is completely wrong, as I said I am not a developer or programmer, I cannot figure out how to get this information into this field and get my original field to still show.

Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` instead of `setAttribute`

```
document.getElementById("dData_DOH").value = custom_calculateDate();
```

Comment: I am sorry I thought when I responded above it would respond to all. I apologize for that. No, I am still having problems, but it is better.

Answer (score 0):

Wow wow wow.

I'll try to rewrite your code by giving you explainations about why:

```
// Firstly, the onchange event doesn't work on IE for text inputs, prefer onblur
document.getElementById('dData_DOH').onblur = function(e) {
    // Now let's get some variables
    var hireDate = this.value, // "this" refers to the element that triggered the event
        now = new Date(),
        // You were on the right track for the difference, almost!
        diff = Math.abs(new Date(now.getTime() - hireDate.getTime()))

    // Finally, just don't change the original field, but the one you wanted to modify
    document.getElementById('dData_LengthEmp').value = diff.toTimeString() // Get the time as a readable format
}
```

I haven't tested the solution, but it should get you on the track.

Btw, don't use try/catch.

Comment: I am getting an error  stating getTime is not supported BUT the date is now staying in the DOH field, so that's a plus! Does it matter that the input is selected via a calendar ? I am also confused if I need a separate function to insert the difference of "now-hireDate" into LengthEmp field. Wish I were smarter, it is probably way simpler than I am making it = (

Comment: everytime i hit return it submits my comment sorry for that, I don't know how to turn it off. Here is what I have so far, thank you much! function custom_calculateDate(){
  var hireDate = this.value;
  var now = new Date();
  var diff = Math.abs(new Date(now.getTime() - hireDate.getTime()));
  document.getElementById('dData_LengthEmp').value = diff.toTimeString();
    }

function insertDate() {
  document.getElementById("dData_LengthEmp").value = custom_calculateDate();
    }

Comment: Comments are not for this kind of information :-). Edit your answer instead to add the new information at the end. I can't really see where you're at, there!